# Use Jquery to Detect length of Table for specific description

Tags: jquery, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have piece of code that is working fine but I want to refine it to detect the length of a table and give a description based on that.

This is a product catalog basically, where I use wordpress entries to show 
a description of the product. Most entries contain a table, some do not. If a table exist, a link to specific point in the table is created and when clicked the visitor goes there. When NO table is detected a description to that effect is given.

The refinement I want to make is to add an additional condition where if the length of the table is, lets say, only 4 rows or less there is a different description for that condition such as

```
elTitulo.after("<a href='#tablesp' class='speclink'>Ver BREVE Tabla de Especificaciones</a> ");   (BREVE = BRIEF)
```

and I am not sure how to integrate that part.
Does it require a condition inside the existing condition? Or a whole new condition?

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var elTitulo = $(".entry-title");
        $("tbody").before("<div id='tablesp'></div>");
        if ($('table').length) {
            elTitulo.after("<a href='#tablesp' class='speclink'>Ver Tabla de Especificaciones</a> ");
        } else {
            elTitulo.after("<p class='speclink'>(No hay tabla especial de especificaciones. Breve descripción disponible)</p> ");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but your code assumes there is only one table in the page. Also, adding a `div` insight your `tbody` is also not a good idea.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var elTitulo = $(".entry-title");
    $("tbody").before("<div id='tablesp'></div>");
    if ($('table').length) {

      if($('table tbody tr').length < 4){
        // There are less then 4 rows (not including 4)
        elTitulo.after("<a href='#tablesp' class='speclink'>Ver BREVE Tabla de Especificaciones</a> ");
      } else {
        elTitulo.after("<a href='#tablesp' class='speclink'>Ver Tabla de Especificaciones</a> ");
      }

    } else {
        elTitulo.after("<p class='speclink'>(No hay tabla especial de especificaciones. Breve descripción disponible)</p> ");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Uzbekjon. Yes, good assumption. There is only one table per entry. Regarding the div inside the table, thats because I tried the before() method targeting the 'table' tag and it did not work. Not sure why.

Comment: I have also fixed the **div** inside the table situation. I think it was just a syntax problem of mixing " with '. Thanks!